# How to make use of GPU in windows docker using DDA(discrete device assigment)

Tags: docker, hyper-v, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

As `NVIDIA docker` is not available with `Docker Desktop for Windows`. I am looking for alternatives to get GPU work in docker. When I googled, I came to know about discrete device assigment, on can assign gpu to docker container. But I am not aware of this.

Please help how to get GPU worked using DDA